# Background process vs Foreground Process

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

Is there a difference how a processor executes a background or foreground process or how operating system deals with their scheduling. If there is no difference at processor level between background and foreground job then at which level the difference comes ?

Comment: AFAIK they are the same to the processor, each get schedule the same way. The difference is that the background process will run without any user intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new background process in shell has nothing to do with the way the processor executes it. Only difference is that the shell does not wait for a background process to finish.

Code for a process creation : 
1) fork a process 
2) if (& symbol is present at the end of command) 
    continue to accept new command
   else
    wait on pid of child.

The only difference is whether the shell reduces the priority of a background process. The answer is "depends" on the shell you are using. But i don't know any existing shell assigning such dynamic priorities.

Comment: There is also some issues about controlling terminal and process groups.

Comment: @above can you please elaborate on the "terminal and process groups".

Comment: Read the man pages for `execve` and `tty(4)` about controlling terminal and a good Linux programming book eg http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ and http://basepath.com/aup/